# Spring Boot scans Test configuration classes on start up

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot App with the main class as below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

The project structure is

```
App/
    src/main/java
    src/test/java
```

In the test package , I have a configuration class used for Integration testing and the class is marked as @TestConfiguration. I am noticing that this class is getting picked up on the server startup. I am using profile as dev on start up. Any idea why the test configuration classes are getting loaded on startup of the application. I need these classes to be scanned only during test phase.

This works well when i run java -jar command from command line, but fails during start up from STS eclipse.

Comment: Don't use eclipse :). In my experience Eclipse is terrible in separating the test and runtime classpath.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Integration project: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration. Please, be careful when you choose tags for your questions.

Comment: Has this been resolved by anyone? I had the same question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837748/testconfiguration-mock-objects-incorrectly-used-in-actual-non-test-spring-boo